# How to set ImageView over ImageView in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, baseadapter

Suppose I have multiple images that I want to set on top of the other, how can I do this in GridView?

Like:
Background
ImageView1
ImageView2 at bottom-right of the ImageView2

Here is an example for what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS36H.png

Here is my codes
Activity:

```
public class ImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ColorMatrixColorFilter cf;
    String Questions = Question.Questions;
    int level = Levels.level;

    public ImgAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        //matrix.setSaturation(0); //0 means grayscale
        matrix.setSaturation(0);
        cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return ThumbIds.length;

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Questions, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        int size = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageResource(ThumbIds[position]);



        if(pref.getBoolean(level+"answered"+position, false)){

            //Thats the ImageView I want to set over the another ImageView
            /*ImageView answ;
            answ = new ImageView(mContext);
            answ.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            answ.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            answ.setImageResource(R.drawable.answered);*/

            imageView.setImageResource(ThumbIds[position]+1);
        }

        return imageView;

    }


    public static Integer[] ThumbIds =
        {
        R.drawable.1,
        R.drawable.2,
        R.drawable.3,
        R.drawable.4,
        R.drawable.5,
        R.drawable.6,
        R.drawable.7
        };  

}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/layout" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Correct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        />

<GridView 
android:id="@+id/Question"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
android:numColumns="3"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
tools:context=".Question" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Question activity I get the GridView

Comment: Have you tried using relative/frame layouts and stacking image view on top of each other that way?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately GridViews don't like it when cells try to overlap each other.  So lets say you have a cell within a gridview that's 48x48dp.  Attempting to render anything that's bigger then 48 will cause it to get clipped.  So that means you'll need to do a trick of the eye sorta thing.

Lets say you want to show the main image at 48x48dp.  Lets call the second guy an emblem whose 16x16dp and you want it centered at the bottom right corner of the main image.  Then you'll need a cell that's about 56dp. If you bring padding or margin into the mix, you may need to adjust.  Doing something akin to the following for each item's layout within the GridView should do the trick.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    ....any other attributes>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:src="Your main image"
        ...any other attributes/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:src="Your main image"
        ...any other attributes/>

</FrameLayout>
```